# server requests, how to handle them?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I have this application that has a form with a drop-down list and a button.

After the form is submitted, another form is loaded in the page using ajax. this happens 5 times.

all forms are the same and contain only a drop-down list and a button.

also each form has attached to it a mysql query that determines what each drop-down will contain.

My question deals with the server requests. I believe that in this application i do 5 server requests, one for each form .

Is it better to create a single page that contain all forms vs the app described above?

i am talking at a load on 80.000 people hitting this application

thanks

edit:

the app works like this:

there is a drop down -> user selects a option and submits ---with ajax---> another form is loaded, a query is made based on previous selection -> user selects a option and submits....etc 5 times

Comment: If your users open 5 pages of your website, you still have 5 requests, but not many concerns about performance I think...It's pretty much the same. Back to your question, you could place the 5 form in the same page and hide/unhide through JS, but I don't know if this can be your intended workflow

Comment: Are the dropdowns dependent? If no, you can get all the dropdowns with a single request, otherwise you can't use fewer as 5 request(one for each dropdown).

Comment: If the next selection is reliant on the one that preceded it eg Choosing a State -> City. You can't know the City until you've selected the State

Comment: @Stoosh so, for my example, i have no choice but to make 5 requests, or how else i can build the app?

Comment: I believe this could be slightly premature. Do you have benchmarks to actually know if this will be a problem yet?

Comment: Well, my advice is don't try and guess what performance problems might come later, let proper testing and analysis be the judge of what needs refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - no need to hit the db every time...  unless the forms are data driven and the  mysql query uses input from the users.  I would build the whole form into the JavaScript beforehand.

Comment: if you have dependent dropdowns, you will have one request per dropdown.